# SQL Server 2008 local connection an error occurred during the pre-login handshake

Tags: sql-server, windows

I am getting an error while trying to connect to SQL locally either via a web application or SQL management Studio. Oddly, I can connect fine remotely via apps on other servers or SQL management on my desktop.

The error is: 
SQL - an error occurred during the pre-login handshake.

EDIT
I have tried the winsock command listed on the other page I have tried adding tcp:servername,1433 to the Registry as Suggested elsewhere on here.
I have tried running this fix it from Microsoft 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2643584 
I am still getting the same issue which is that SQL Agent cannot start, if I re-enable SSL3 and reboot all works fine disable again and here is the error i recieve

> 2014-11-24 21:03:34 - ! [000] Unable to connect to server
>   'tcp:servername,1433'; SQLServerAgent cannot start 2014-11-24 21:03:34
>   - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 10054, TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. [SQLSTATE 08001]  2014-11-24
>   21:03:34 - ! [298] SQLServer Error: 10054, Client unable to establish
>   connection [SQLSTATE 08001]  2014-11-24 21:03:34 - ! [382] Logon to
>   server 'tcp:servername,1433' failed (DisableAgentXPs) 2014-11-24
>   21:03:35 - ? [098] SQLServerAgent terminated (normally)

Comment: sorry i did try that

Comment: You need to be specific regarding exactly what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things it could be, including:

- Network or firewall between the affected apps and the SQL Server
- Something related to [your previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/644337/disabled-sslv3-to-combat-poodle-now-cannot-connect-to-sql-connection-forcibly-c)
- One of the answers in [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/423013/sql-an-error-occurred-during-the-pre-login-handshake)

Hopefully, that gives you some things to try.